# Workload substantially increased, very unhappy

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, work-life-balance, workload

I'm currently in a situation where our company (which is fairly small) went out and bought another struggling company. I am a software developer (the only one at my company after another was let go) and at the new company, there were 5. 3 were laid off, however, the 2 that were kept resigned. I'm now the only developer for both companies; and as a lot of issues have risen from the new company, I've had to go in and try to learn their infrastructure (usually up until past midnight combing through it).

I've requested help which they're looking into, but in all honesty, I'm just unhappy at this company now. The only issue is, as the only developer, it feels like they would be hurt significantly (maybe even irrecoverably) by my departure. There are people here that would suffer and I don't want to do that.

I'm just not sure what to do. I'm miserable here, but I can't bring myself to pull the trigger. I'm not sure a compensation bump alone would help, which I also hate bringing up ( I brought it up 4 months ago and I was told they'd "look into it" and it's only been brought up once again "we haven't forgotten").

I'm not sure what to do at this stage. We don't really have an HR department to speak with; all interaction would have to be with my manager.

Edit: Should I feel responsible for coworkers who would suffer as a result? Some I consider friends. Should I be looking for a new job?

Comment: As it stands, this post is off-topic. What is your question? What goal do you want to achieve? Remember that we can't tell you whether you should quit your job or not.

Comment: You have put up with the workload of what used to be 6 programmers for 4 months and they have not "forgotten".   That is abuse.  1 programmer is just bad business management.  I would start with working normal days and put out a resume.

Comment: I will make this very easy for you. *Nobody is indispensable.* Not you, not me. People will figure out a way to go on with or without you. So stop carrying unnecessary burdens on your shoulder. By the way, a relevant quote I read elsewhere today in this site is applicable to you too ... cemeteries are full of people who thought the world couldn't go on without them.

Answer (score 5):

1. Stop working all the hours.  Go to your manager, tell you realize they are short staffed, but you cannot maintain this schedule and will be limiting hours to set times 9-5 or whatever you feel is fair.  If they balk, tell them it's this or you walk right there.
2. Start looking.  This merger is not going to end well, if they lost their entire team besides you, there is a reason, and unless you have a significant ownership stake in this it's time to pull the plug.
3. If you decide to stay indicate you want something for it.  Say a deal where you get a huge bonus if you stay for 6 months, something like that.  Make sure it is in writing and that if they terminate the deal you get a prorated bonus.  This is not unusual in mergers for key employees, you could mention that.  In all likelihood some of management may already have these.
4. Also, if you stay indicate they absolutely have to get more people.  If you see them dragging and you didn't get the deal in 3, do 2, and walk.  This is on them not you, you didn't agree to the merger, you don't have a financial stake in this, you are just a hired gun.

Comment: Yeah...this one kind of answers itself.  If you're unhappy then leave.  Or ask to be put in charge of the department beginning with hiring two people.  But your employeers are obviously not going to make you happy or they would have by now.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere how are you supposed to find a job when you are working 24x7 for this failed merger.  That is the point, the OP is finished, it time to walk and this is a last chance effort for the employer to avoid that.  This isn't an ultimatum, this is the hail marry with 2s left on the clock.  The OP just needs to see if the employer is willing to play ball or not.

Comment: 1 is a good solution that works for me. I have a lot on my plate, but I always make it clear that I work only 40 hours a week and then I am done (exception made when for example we have server issues or I released some bugs by accident). Just make sure you use that time well....for example do not go writing comments on this website while at work....woeps.